# rbenvとruby-buildをインストール「-bash: rbenv: コマンドが見つかりません」

Tags: rbenv

#### 前提・実現したいこと

AWSのEC2サーバー上でRuby on Railsが動くように環境構築しています。
benvとruby-buildをインストールしていたのですが、こちらがうまくいきません。

#### 試したこと・発生している問題

```
#rbenvのインストール
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-189 ~]$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv 
#パスを通す
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-189 ~]$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile 
#rbenvを呼び出すための記述
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-189 ~]$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
#.bash_profileの読み込み
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-25-189 ~]$ source .bash_profile
-bash: rbenv: コマンドが見つかりません←
```

$ source .bash_profile をすると
「-bash: rbenv: コマンドが見つかりません」と表示されます。

rbenvを呼び出す方のがうまくいっていないとは思うのですが、パスの記述がよくわかっていません。。
もしお詳しい方いらっしゃいましたら教えていただければ嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init` は通りますか？

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、通りませんでした。
「-bash: /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」
このように表示されます。

Comment: となると git clone が失敗していそうな気がします。`ls ~/.rbenv` や `ls ~/.rbenv/bin` などしておかしなことになっていないか確かめてみてください。パッと見た感じだと、質問文にある手順自体はおかしくないような気がします。

Comment: もしかすると GitHub のリポジトリが sstephenson/rbenv -> rbenv/rbenv になったのが上手く反映されていないのかも……？　もしこのあたりの修正で解決すれば自己回答していただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: そもそも `git` コマンドがインストールされていない、なんてことはないですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。gitコマンドはインストールされていました。

$ git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
→fatal: destination path '/home/ec2-user/.rbenv' already exists and is not an empty directory

$PATHがおかしいのかなと思うのですがいかがでしょうか↓
$ echo $PATH
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

Comment: すみません見にくくなったので書き直します。「$ echo $PATH ▶︎ /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin:/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin」

Comment: $ ls ~/.rbenv/bin ▶︎ 
「ls: /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/bin にアクセスできません: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」　このように出ました。

Comment: 他の方も書かれていますが、やはり`git clone`が失敗しているように見えます。`~/.rbenv` ディレクトリを削除してみて `git clone`からやり直してみてはいかがでしょう。